# Issue with updating a dictionary in for loop (not unique)

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have an issue with populating a dictionary from the database. It overwrites or merges values that from my logic should be unique to the given country.

```
country_list=[]
for countries in item_obj.values('ship_country'):
    if countries['ship_country'] not in country_list:
        country_list.append(countries['ship_country'])
country_dict = {}
for country in country_list:
    country_dict.update({country: []})

cat_dict = { i : {} for i in ProductCategories.objects.filter(user=request.user) }

for country in country_list:
    country_dict[country].append(cat_dict)

# outputs: country_dict = {'Netherlands': [{'Games': {}, 'Bikes': {}, 'Paint': {}}], 'Belgium': [{'Games': {}, 'Bikes': {}, 'Paint': {}}]}

for country, value in country_dict.items():
    for key in value:
        for category in key:
            for channel in channel_list:        
                if channel in channels:
                    aggr = item_obj.filter(
                        country=country, 
                        category=category,
                        channel=channel).aggregate(Sum('price'))
                
                    if aggr['price__sum'] != None:
                        key[category] = {channel: round(aggr['price__sum'], 2)}
```

which gives me if i print out line for line, exactly what i want see:

```
Netherlands
Games
{'price__sum': None}
{}
Bikes
{'Channel #3': Decimal('30.10')}
Paint
{'Channel #1': Decimal('56.70')}

Belgium
Games
{'price__sum': None}
{}
Bikes
{'Channel #1': Decimal('39.70')}
Paint
{'Channel #2': Decimal('13.90')}
```

But when I print the final dictionary it overwrites the unique Netherlands values...

```
{
   "Netherlands":[
      {
         "Games":{
            
         },
         "Bikes":{
            "channel #1": "Decimal(""39.70"")"
         },
         "Sprays":{
            "channel #2": "Decimal(""13.90"")"
         }
      }
   ],
   "Belgium":[
      {
         "Games":{
            
         },
         "Bikes":{
            "channel #1": "Decimal(""39.70"")"
         },
         "Paint":{
            "channel #2": "Decimal(""13.90"")"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

if I use update() instead of =

```
if aggr['price__sum'] != None:
    key[category].update({channel: round(aggr['price__sum'], 2)})
```

it merges the two together like this:

```
{
   "Netherlands":[
      {
         "Games":{
            
         },
         "Bikes":{
            "Channel #3":"Decimal(""30.10"")",
            "channel #1":"Decimal(""39.70"")"
         },
         "Paint":{
            "Channel #1":"Decimal(""56.70"")",
            "channel #2":"Decimal(""13.90"")"
         }
      }
   ],
   "Belgium":[
      {
         "Games":{
            
         },
         "Bikes":{
            "Channel #3":"Decimal(""30.10"")",
            "channel #1":"Decimal(""39.70"")"
         },
         "Paint":{
            "Channel #1":"Decimal(""56.70"")",
            "channel #2":"Decimal(""13.90"")"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

It seems that update or = ignores the fact that we are in a different country and I tried a lot and am stuck, I seem to miss something. Can anyone help me? :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the actual initialization of `country_dict` is NOT what you posted here.  You're somehow using the same value of `[{'Games': {}, 'Bikes': {}, 'Paint': {}}]` for all countries.

Comment: I've updated, so you can see how country_dict came to existence...

Comment: Instead of expanding like that, please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: You are creating a `cat_dict` and afterwards initialize your countries with this `cat_dict`. All countries are using the same dictionary. Move the `cat_dict` inside the for loop.